# Why the defaultly initialized value of an integer is 4200187 in C++?

Tags: c++, initialization, clion

from 2.2.1 variable definitions of "C++ primer" , "variables defined outside any function body are initialized to zero". However, like the following code, I define an integer i and print it out. why the result is 4200187? (I use Clion)

Update: thank you for your anwsers! now I know that i is defined inside the main function, and then i is not defined. But why an undefined integer has the value os 4200187?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int i;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

the result:

```
4200187

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `i` is not defined outside any function. It is not initialized.

Comment: You declared it, but not initialized. Also, *main* **is** a function. In C/C++, that means that initial value is *undefined*.

Comment: *"outside any function body"* - `main` is a function too.

Comment: *"variables defined outside any function body"* `i` is not defiend outside of a function body, it is defined in the body of the `main` function, so the *"are initialized to zero"* doesn't apply.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number  so i is considered to be initialized inside the main function? then why the value is 4200187 if it is not defined?

Comment: It isn't initialised to a default value.   A variable (of a basic type like `int`) of automatic storage duration is *uninitialised*.   Accessing its value gives undefined behaviour.    This means any result of your code is possible.   If you run your code a week from now, the value output may be completely different.

Comment: not defined means it is not defined what the value is. Getting 4200187 as output is as good as any other output because your code has undefined behavior. The C++ standard defines what code does that has defined behavior, it does not say anything about the output of code with undefined behavior

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number - Practically, most implementations (compilers) will result in this program outputting some value, but that value could be anything.   Technically, because the behaviour is undefined according to the standard, this code isn't even guaranteed to produce output. It, could, notionally reformat a hard drive or - if the host system has suitable hardware - electrocute the programmer.   Given how often this sort of question is asked, electrocuting a programmer may be desirable in improving the average programmer understanding of what undefined behaviour is.

Comment: @Nastor -- your comment is essentially correct, but it should be "You **defined** it". A declaration says "there's a thing with this name somewhere"; a definition says "here it is". A definition is also a declaration, but it doesn't go the other way around.

Comment: `int i;` is not default initialized, it is uninitialized.  `int i{};` is default initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the document you're referring to is talking about this kind of variables:

```
#include <iostream>

int i;

int main() {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Variables declared this way are guaranteed to be initialized at 0 whereas non-static primitive variables created inside of a function are uninitialized.

According to the specification reading from an uninitialized variable causes undefined behavior and your compiler should print out a warning if you try.

Hence, the value you got isn't an "expected value" from C++, just a value your compiler felt like printing this one time. As 463035818_is_not_a_number said, undefined behavior is just that, undefined. Most compiler will try to be nice and preserve as much of the functionality of the program as possible (that's probably why it still printed something to the console) but I'd recommend against trusting it with that, **anything** can happen.

Comment: pedantically, also trying OPs code one could see a `0` as ouput, and trying your code and getting a `0` as output is not conclusive. However, you are right that global variables are initialized

Comment: Technically (pedantically) "_I just tried on my machine_" doesn't mean anything, when talking about C++. Since if code had undefined behavior - you might get expected output by sheer coincidence.

Comment: True, I'll edit my post to reflect your comments

Comment: "it's whatever was in memory at this address before your program ran" is from a common misunderstanding that code would be instructions for the cpu, but it is not. Code is an abstract description of what the resulting program should do. When you confront the compiler with code that has UB it may produce anything as output. It may produce an executable that reads some unexpected value from some memory, but when optimizations are turned on the compiler might also produce an executable from OPs code that does the same as this code: `int main() {}`

Comment: _"Variables created inside of a function are uninitialized"_ — I don't think this is generally correct. IIRC, for instance, static variables are zero-intialized even when declared inside a function.